# spring hibernate.connection.release_mode default value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring boot version 1.5.4.RELEASE & spring data jpa

What is default value for **spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.release_mode**, how to display that value once application starts?

**EDIT :** Answer added below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.lo.sb.event.util.test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ConnectionPoolParamsClr implements CommandLineRunner {

  @PersistenceUnit
  EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);

    System.out.println("\n\n===================== properties =====================");
    System.out.println(
        "sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getConnectionReleaseMode() = " + sessionFactory
            .getSessionFactoryOptions().getConnectionReleaseMode());

  }

}
```